# Java GitHub API -org.kohsuke.github Clone repository to Local Machine

Tags: java, git, github, github-api

This might be duplicate, but I don't see any solution or proper documentation or Example. I'm trying to download a Git Hub repository to my local machine. The following is what I tried. I'm using **org.kohsuke.github** API. I don't see any proper method to download to local.

```
public void cloneRep() {
    String login = "userid";
    String password = "password";
    String rep = "repository";
    String localDir = "/home/myuser/repository/";
    try {
        System.out.println("Connecting...." + login + " : " + password);
        GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingPassword(login, password);
        boolean isValid = gitHub.isCredentialValid();
        System.out.println("is Valid ? " + isValid);
        if (isValid) {
            GHRepository repository = gitHub.getRepository(rep);
            //how to clone the repository to local directory?
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION....");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know with **org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git** it is possible.

```
String remoteUrl = new StringBuffer().append("https").append(login)
                .append(":").append(password).append("@github.com/")
                .append(login).append("/").append(rep).toString();
org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remoteUrl).setDirectory(localDir)
                    .call();
```

But that seems more complex. First I need to do authentication only. And then I need to download to local. I'm not interested to use both. If the API provides a better solution, I can use that.

IS there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but the **org.kohsuke.github** API is about manipulating repositories and gists on github. It isn't about cloning repositories locally or performing other git related activities.

Answer (score 2):

JGit is already being discussed in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jgit

get JGit libraries using your pom.xml or download the JAR files manually

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.201506090130-r</version>
</dependency>
```

And try this example

[JGit: Cannot find a tutorial or simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example) or correspondingly follow the url inside the discussion

To authenticate you can use CloneCommand with setNoCheckout(true);

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;
.......
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File("C:\\myfolder"));
cloneCommand.setNoCheckout(true);
cloneCommand.setRemote( "https://github.com/<username>/<repositoru>.git" );
cloneCommand.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "<username>", "<password>" ) );
cloneCommand.call();
```

c:\myfolder should not be created manually, it will be created automatically

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to simply authenticate too?

Comment: Hi Sorry it is throwing `JGitInternalException: Destination path ".git" already exists and is not an empty directory` even if the credentials are correct and repository also correct

Comment: Actually it created empty folder in my home directory with repository name

Comment: This is actually cloning the repository. I just need to do authentication.

Comment: You can use cloneCommand.setNoCheckout(true); which will not clone

Answer (score 2):

I created a utility class for this :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProvider;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;


public class GithubClient {



/**
 * @param githubRemoteUrl Remote git http url which ends with .git.
 * @param accessToken     Personal access token.
 * @param branchName Name of the branch which should be downloaded
 * @param destinationDir  Destination directory where the downloaded files should be present.
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public boolean downloadRepoContent(@NotNull String githubRemoteUrl, @NotNull String accessToken, @NotNull String branchName, @NotNull String destinationDir) throws Exception {
    //String githubSourceUrl, String accessToken
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(accessToken, "");
    URL fileUrl = new URL("file://"+destinationDir);
    File destinationFile = FileUtils.toFile(fileUrl);
    //delete any existing file
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(destinationFile);
    Git.cloneRepository().setURI(githubSourceUrl)
            .setBranch(branchName)
            .setDirectory(destinationFile)
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .call();
    if(destinationFile.length() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```